# Why won't this picture load in, in LibGDX, I can't find anything to help fix this on youtube and other websites

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to make a picture load in, using LibGdx, but I keep getting this error when I try.
I don
t understand what this error means, and I can't find the answer to it on youtube.

error: cannot find symbol
private Texture img;
^
symbol:   class Texture
location: class AndroidLauncher

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    }
    private Texture img;
    private Sprite sprite;

    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("sadgameslogo1.png");
        sprite = new Sprite(img);
    }

    public void render ()  {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        sprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: when you are missing imports, click cursor on the code with the error, press Alt+Enter, and it will give you the option to add the import automatically.

Comment: It seems to have stopped all the errors, but when I try it on the android emulator I get this
Error while waiting for device: Could not start AVD

Comment: The emulator is no good for testing games anyway. You’ll have a frame rate that looks like a slide show. Test the desktop module or on an actual device.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;` to the imports.

Comment: I did that, I get error: cannot find symbol
 private Sprite sprite;
         ^
  symbol:   class Sprite
  location: class AndroidLauncher

Comment: It occurs here
private Sprite sprite;

Comment: How about com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite? No, If you get another error of this kind, you can go to https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/ and  search (Ctrl+F) for the Name of the class, that wasn't found.

Comment: Ok, so I just found out that this is happening too, 
 error: package Gdx does not exist
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
and I cannot seem to find it, even with Ctrl+F

Comment: You have to import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx

Comment: Yeah those errors stopped coming, thanks, I'm just going to try and find out why I'm still getting
error: cannot find symbol
  batch = new SpriteBatch();
              ^
  symbol:   class SpriteBatch
  location: class AndroidLauncher

Comment: You have to import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch